# What critter (insect?) removes sand from between paving bricks?

Tags: brick, mortar, pavers, insect

Something is excavating sand/mortar from between paving bricks, as seen here.  I thought it was ants, but I've placed ant traps and bait and there seems to be no effect. Also, when the mounds are disturbed, no insects are visible.

[image]

Here's a close-up view of the large pile at the left.

[image]

That's a significant amount of sand/mortar being removed.

If it's not ants, what insect is causing this?

Comment: Good question, thank you for including photographs.

Answer (score 4):

Sidewalk ants are a thing. They are very tiny. But there are also many species of wasp that do this, and are difficult to spot since they spend time either underground or in flight.